# How to get percentages?

Tags: sql, sqlite, percentage

```
SELECT
    date,
    location,
    total_cases,
    total_deaths,
    (total_deaths/total_cases)* 100 as Death_percentage
FROM CovidDeaths
ORDER BY 1,2
```

From my query (to get percentage of COVID deaths per location) `death_percentage` column returns 0 for every row. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [ask] https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Why do people so often forget or refuse to prevent divide by zero exceptions when doing divisions? Such obvious issues should be ruled out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is integer division. Since both operands are integers, SQLite returns an *integer* result (basically the floor of the result of the division).

```
SELECT ( 2 / 3 ) * 100;
--> 0
```

Here, since the denominator of the division is always greater than the numerator, the division always yields `0`. We can work around this with a little trick, by turning the `100` multiplier to a decimal value and putting it first in the calculation. It is also important to remove the parentheses around the division, so the decimal typing properly "propagates" to the division:

```
SELECT 100.0 * 2 / 3
--> 66.666667
```

In your query:

```
SELECT
    date,
    location,
    total_cases,
    total_deaths,
    100.0 * total_deaths / nullif(total_cases, 0) as death_percentage
FROM CovidDeaths
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Note that the expression also adresses the possibility of a `0` values in the `total_cases` column - which would otherwise generate an arithmetic error, as pointed out by Jonas Metzler in the comments.